# check value before creating table row

Tags: php

How I can check value before adding value into cell?

I have issue with table when I want create slot duration based table. Duration and price of that service ex. massage.

My foreach loop will add all values into one column "45min";

My code:

```
$tableRow = array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'name' => 'Green tea care',
    'id' => 3265,
    'slot' => '45min',
    'price' => '30',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'name' => 'Coconut care',
    'id' => 3260,
    'slot' => '1h',
    'price' => '50',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'name' => 'Coconut care',
    'id' => 3260,
    'slot' => '1,5h',
    'price' => '65',
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'name' => 'Coconut care',
    'id' => 3260,
    'slot' => '2h',
    'price' => '77',
  ),
  4 => 
  array (
    'name' => 'Mango care',
    'id' => 3255,
    'slot' => '1h',
    'price' => '50€',
  ),
  5 => 
  array (
    'name' => 'Mango care',
    'id' => 3255,
    'slot' => '1,5h',
    'price' => '65',
  ),
  6 => 
  array (
    'name' => 'Mango care',
    'id' => 3255,
    'slot' => '2h',
    'price' => '77',
  ),
  7 => 
  array (
    'name' => 'Siami tea care',
    'id' => 3253,
    'slot' => '45min',
    'price' => '30',
  ),
  8 => 
  array (
    'name' => 'Siami tea face care',
    'id' => 3249,
    'slot' => '1,5h',
    'price' => '67',
  ),
  9 => 
  array (
    'name' => 'Siami tea face care',
    'id' => 3249,
    'slot' => '2h',
    'price' => '80',
  ),
)
    
        $arr_a = array("45min", "1h", "1,5h", "2h", "1h", "1,5h", "2h", "45min", "1,5h", "2h");
        $arr_a = array_count_values($arr_a);
        $table = '<div class="product-table-wrap product-table-responsive">
                    <table class="product-table">
                        <thead class="product-table-head">
                            <tr class="product-table-row">
                                <th class="product-table-cell category-title"><span class="product-pricing-text">'.$cat_name.'</span></th>';
        //if time slot not exist in array_a then it doesnt show this table head.
        ($arr_a['45min'] > 0 ? $table .= '<th class="product-table-cell product-duration"><span class="product-pricing-text">45min</span></th>' : '');
        ($arr_a['1h'] > 0 ? $table .= '<th class="product-table-cell product-duration"><span class="product-pricing-text">1h</span></th>' : '');
        ($arr_a['1,5h'] > 0 ? $table .= '<th class="product-table-cell product-duration"><span class="product-pricing-text">1,5h</span></th>' : '');
        ($arr_a['2h'] > 0 ? $table .= '<th class="product-table-cell product-duration"><span class="product-pricing-text">2h</span></th>' : '');    
        ($arr_a['2,5h'] > 0 ? $table .= '<th class="product-table-cell product-duration"><span class="product-pricing-text">2,5h</span></th>' : '');    
        ($arr_a['3h'] > 0 ? $table .= '<th class="product-table-cell product-duration"><span class="product-pricing-text">3h</span></th>' : '');    
        
        $table .= '</tr>
            </thead>';
        $table .= '<tbody class="product-table-body">';
        
        //here is the issue with foreach loop. It will loop each price to each row. But it should be 1 row each cell
        foreach ($tableRow as $row) {
            $table .= '<tr>';
            $table .= '<td class="product-table-cell category-title"><span class="product-pricing-text">'.$row["name"].'</span></td>';
            ($row['slot'] == '45min' ? $table .= '<td class="product-table-cell product-duration"><a href="#" class="product-pricing-text">'.$row["price"].'</span></td>' : '');
            ($row['slot'] == '1h' ? $table .= '<td class="product-table-cell product-duration"><a href="#" class="product-pricing-text">'.$row["price"].'</span></td>' : '');
            ($row['slot'] == '1,5h' ? $table .= '<td class="product-table-cell product-duration"><a href="#" class="product-pricing-text">'.$row["price"].'</span></td>' : '');
            ($row['slot'] == '2h' ? $table .= '<td class="product-table-cell product-duration"><a href="#" class="product-pricing-text">'.$row["price"].'</span></td>' : '');   
            ($row['slot'] == '2,5h' ? $table .= '<td class="product-table-cell product-duration"><a href="#" class="product-pricing-text">'.$row["price"].'</span></td>' : ''); 
            ($row['slot'] == '3h' ? $table .= '<td class="product-table-cell product-duration"><a href="#" class="product-pricing-text">'.$row["price"].'</span></td>' : '');
            $table .= '</tr>';
        }
        
        $table .= '<tr class="product-table-row">
                    <td class="product-table-cell category-title"><span class="product-pricing-text">Thai massage</span></td>
                    <td class="product-table-cell product-duration"><a href="#" class="product-pricing-text">48,00</a></td>
                    <td class="product-table-cell product-duration"><span class="product-pricing-text">66,00</span></td>
                    <td class="product-table-cell product-duration"><span class="product-pricing-text">78,00</span></td>
                    <td class="product-table-cell product-duration"><span class="product-pricing-text">93,00</span></td>
                    <td class="product-table-cell product-duration"><span class="product-pricing-text">108,00</span></td>
                </tr>';
                
            $table .= '</tbody>
        </table>
    </div>';
        
        echo $table;
```

My current table output looks like this:

| Care | 45min | 1h | 1,5h | 2h |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Green tea care | 30 |  |  |  |
| Coconut care | 50 |  |  |  |
| Coconut care | 65 |  |  |  |
| Coconut care | 77 |  |  |  |
| Mango care | 50 |  |  |  |
| Mango care | 65 |  |  |  |
| Mango care | 77 |  |  |  |
| Siami tea care | 30 |  |  |  |
| Siami tea face care | 67 |  |  |  |
| Siami tea face care | 80 |  |  |  |

But it should look like this:

| Care | 45min | 1h | 1,5h | 2h |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Green tea care | 30 |  |  |  |
| Coconut care |  | 50 | 65 | 77 |
| Mango care |  | 50 | 65 | 77 |
| Siami tea care | 30 |  |  |  |
| Siami tea face care |  |  | 67 | 80 |

Comment: You should do a global switch instead of all this if.

Comment: Can you describe the problem in a bit more detail please, perhaps add a comparison between what it outputs, and what you want it to output? You say "it should be one row each cell", but each of the table rows you output seems to have two cells - the product name and the price. If you want those on separate rows, you'll need to add appropriate row closing and opening tags between them.

Comment: @droopsnoot added two output tables.

Comment: You are foreaching over every tableRow and rendering a new row. For this to work, you'll need to flip this array such that the key is the "care" with a value of each of the durations.

Comment: What you mean flipping array?

Comment: No - that's the problem you have above. If your key is the care name:
`array('Mango Care' => array('slot' => 1,5h', 'price' => '65'))` then you can have multiple slots listed while only having one copy of the care name. Then you render each care name with each of the slots as additional columns.

Comment: IMHO the best approach is to re-organize your input data first - so that the data is grouped by name first, and slot second - https://3v4l.org/W74fb Now you can loop over the first dimension of this to create your rows. Inside, nest a second loop that goes over all your possible slot values - and then check, if the current name _has_ an entry for the current slot (`isset`) - if so, output that into the current cell, else nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to somehow "pad" empty columns to non-matching time slots and merge those similar items into single item.

```
//preprocess the array
$tableRow = array_reduce($tableRow, function($carry, $item) {
  
  //find if the given $item["name"]
  //is already exists and get its position
  $match_index = -1;
  for($i = 0; $i < count($carry); $i++) {
    if($carry[$i]['name'] == $item['name']){
      $match_index = $i;
      break;
    }
  }
  
  if($match_index >= 0){
     //item already exists, update the slot and price
     array_push($carry[$match_index]['slot'], $item['slot']);
     array_push($carry[$match_index]['price'], $item['price']);
  }
  else {
     //item is new, remap the slot and price into array
     $new = array_replace($item, array('slot' => array($item['slot'])));
     $new = array_replace($new, array('price' => array($item['price'])));
     array_push($carry, $new);
  }
  
  return $carry;
}, array());

//printing the array
foreach ($tableRow as $row) {
    $table .= '<tr>';
    $table .= '<td class="product-table-cell category-title"><span class="product-pricing-text">'.$row["name"].'</span></td>';
    
    foreach(array_keys($arr_a) as $slots) {
      $matching = array_search($slots, $row["slot"]);
      if($matching !== false) {
        $table .= '<td class="product-table-cell product-duration"><a href="#" class="product-pricing-text">'.$row["price"][$matching] .'</span></td>';
      }
      else {
        $table .= '<td></td>';
    }
    }
    $table .= '</tr>';
}
```

The preprocessing part will turn the initial array into something like this (taken one part of it):

```
array(5) {
  ...
  [1]=>
  array(4) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(12) "Coconut care"
    ["id"]=>
    int(3260)
    ["slot"]=>
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      string(2) "1h"
      [1]=>
      string(4) "1,5h"
      [2]=>
      string(2) "2h"
    }
    ["price"]=>
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      string(2) "50"
      [1]=>
      string(2) "65"
      [2]=>
      string(2) "77"
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

There are some parts that can be improved, feel free to improve upon it.

Comment: It works and perfect almost for me. I have now figure out how to merge two same column prices.  ex.: `1,5h (4ppl) 100€` and `1,5h (5ppl) 150€` then it would be under `1,5h 100€ / 150€`